# Would like Devise Models::Recoverable to send different reset instructions based on user state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Our User model contains a parameter called user_state. We would like to send four different email instructions on how and why the user must reset their password based on the user_state: new_user, password_forgotten (user has requested to reset password), inactive (account hasn't been used lately), and suspended (login disabled due to some undesirable behavior).

In all of the above states, we would first like to set the current password to a random password and then send a custom email for each state type.

I have found the Devise `send_reset_password_instructions` method which sends the reset email. But I can not figure out a reasonable way to send different email content based on the user_state listed above.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by polymorphing the mailer view. Lets assume you have the `reset_password_email(user)` method in your `UserMailer` to send that message. And you have 2 possible states: `master` and `slave` (just an example).

So then to generate 2 different message bodies you put them in different partials in `app/views/user_mailer/_master.html.erb` and `app/views/user_mailer/_slave.html.erb` (or whatever html parser you are using, I prefer slim).

And then you just need to put the correct call in your `app/views/user_mailer/reset_password_email.html.erb` like this:

`<%= render partial: @user.state, user: @user %>`